# How can we know we are not in edit page

Tags: functions

I want to enqueue a JS file only to my View Page screen(after pubishing page).
Whenever I click on edit this page, i want to remove that JS.

How can we do this.

```
`if(is_page()){
wp_register_script( 'xxx', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'xxx' );
```

}`

But I am not able to get the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code in the functions.php file at your theme's folder

```
    function my_enqueue($hook) {
        if ( 'edit.php' == $hook ) {
            return;
        }

        wp_register_script( 'xxx', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/js/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'xxx' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

The [admin_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action hook can also be used to target a specific admin page.

Comment: ok. So is it ok now?

Comment: Much better. At least now, anyone in future finding this will know what is going on in your answer :-)

Comment: Yes , it worked